React jest testing submenu from ant design
I have a component that is rendering only for admins,
I wanna make a test case to see if it appears on the screen or if it is present for admins.
Unfortunately, I didn't succeed it.
The component is placed into a NavBar, on the third position on the navbar there is a submenu called 'user', and when you hover over it, the submenu expands and there are 3 buttons: Logout, Code list and reset user password.
I wawnna check if the reset user password appears for admins.
I tried using waitFor but I'm using an older version of react, tried using waitForElement but it appears that it never renders, it is indeed situated somewhere at the end of the HTML code, not visible on the screen, with the tag Reset user password
I made sure that the fake user data constant was composed of an id of user and a role of admin, so the problem isn't from there.
Any ideea how could I make this test work?
Tried the waitFor, but it seems i'm using an odler version of react.
Tried waitForElement, but it the answer was that the time limit finished without rendering, so it fails no mather what.
I tried through screen rendering, and tought maybe because it's an animation of a submenu, and only when you hover over it the menu is shown, maybe this will work but not
Tried even with querySelector, but still didn't work, the result is either null, either the component wasn't found.
This is the code from the navbar:
{props.userData.id
        ? <SubMenu title={props.userData.id}>
            <Menu.Item key="myCodes">
              <Link to={`/code/feed/${props.userData.id}`}>
                {t('My codes')}
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="logOut">
              <Link to="/logout">{t('Log out')}</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            {props.userData.role === 'ADMIN' && (
              <Menu.Item id='resetPassword' data-testid="resetPassword" key="resetPassword">
                <Link to="/user/admin-reset-password">
                  {t(`Reset user password`)}
                </Link>
              </Menu.Item>
            )}
          </SubMenu>
        : <Menu.Item key="logIn">
            <Link to="/login">{t('Log in')}</Link>
          </Menu.Item>
      }

and the code from the test I tried:
test('Render reset password menu item', () => {
  const fakeUserData = {
    id: 'user',
    role: 'ADMIN'
  };
  const { debug, getByText, getByTestId } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Navbar userData={fakeUserData}/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  const userElement = getByText('user');
  fireEvent.mouseEnter(userElement);
  const resetPasswordElement = queryByTestId('resetPassword');
  expect(resetPasswordElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});

The 'resetPasswordElement' is in the document even if it's not pressed on it, but it seems like, the jest can't find it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
